# How do I add a MapProxy overlay to Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, web-mapping, mapserver, google-maps-api, mapproxy

I have Mapserver running, reading from a raster file, which I can overlay over Google Maps using its Javascript API. Now, for caching of tiles, I need to use MapProxy URL for Google Maps overlay. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install mapproxy on your laptop and use mapproxy-serve to configure correctly mapproxy.

Mapproxy configuration is based on a yaml file.

In this file you need to declare your mapserver URI (WMS, WMTS, TMS, or whatever) as your source.

Then you have to choose a cache directory.

Finally you need to expose a layer.

A configuration example :

```
services:
  demo:
  tms:
    use_grid_names: true

layers:
  - name: my-layer
    title: This is a great layer
    sources: [my-cache]

caches:
  my-cache:
    grids: [GLOBAL_WEBMERCATOR]
    sources: [mapserver]
    format: image/png

sources:
  mapserver:
    type: tile
    url: http://your-map-server-url/tile/%(z)s/%(y)s/%(x)s
    grid: GLOBAL_WEBMERCATOR
```

The Mapproxy configuration documentation is pretty complete: https://mapproxy.org/docs/1.9.0/configuration.html